# Do we need a tag for the Tandy TRS-80 Color Computer?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just realized I have at least four different [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions involving the [Tandy TRS-80 Color Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80_Color_Computer). Does it make sense to add a tag for it? If so, ought it to be [color-computer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-computer)? [tandy-color-computer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tandy-color-computer)? [trs-80](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trs-80)?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think it adds much value but neither is it damaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it matters either way but without a good case that we do need it I'd err on the side of not creating it.

> When should I create new tags?
>
> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always favor existing tags; **only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.**
>
> <sub>[Help Center > Privileges > Create tags](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)</sub>

Currently these questions are covered under [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games), I'm not sure a [trs-80-color-computer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trs-80-color-computer) would add much value on top of that. Besides if you're mentioning it in the text you're not really increasing it's "searchability" only the categorisation.

Comment: To be honest this seems to me to be one of those tags that _could_ be useful but without an argument saying why it would be I can't see it and so see no need for it.

Comment: That does make sense.

Answer (score -3):

I think it could be a useful tag, so I'd err on the side of creating it.

Like I've said before, a tag is a Bat-signal for experts. And *expert* is quite broad here: professional experts, avid fans, creators of content, and so on.

In this case, you're trying to identify a work that was published on a given platform, that platform being the Tandy TRS-80 Color Computer. You're likely to get an answer from someone who is an expert — in some fashion — on the Tandy TRS-80 Color Computer.
How would you attract such an expert? By tagging your question with [tandy-color-computer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tandy-color-computer) or a similar suitable tag.

Comment: Also makes sense. :-D

Comment: 1 reason against this we don't want platform specific tags for everything, that's just going to create a web of noise. Starting down that road will lead to trouble later on. PC game? `[pc]`, `[windows]`, `[windows-7]` etc. And that's before consoles and what not.

Comment: [[tag:video-games]] doesn't have _that many_ questions that we really need to start mini categories within it.

Comment: And FWIW I think we should usually err on the side of ___not___ creating a tag if we don't need it. Our tag system is already a mess, we don't need more tags for no good reason just because to help clutter and confuse matters.